# I want to apply unit tests to simple numeric playback code

Tags: python, unit-testing

I recently started programming with Python for the first time. I have been told that I can not access the essence of unit testing for this code. I tried to practice by listening to the importance of unit testing and Python unit testing.

The code is shown below.

```
# UpDown.py

import random
import unittest

servicenumber = 0
exp = 0

## Game play screen
def start_screen():
    global servicenumber
    exe = """
==============================
1. Up/Down Game Start
2. Exp check
3. exit
==============================
Please enter your desired service number."""

    print(exe)
    servicenumber = input()
    if servicenumber == 1:
        start_game()
    elif servicenumber == 2:
        check_exp()
    elif servicenumber == 3:
        game_exit()
    else:
        print "Please enter one of 1, 2, or 3."


## Up/Down This is the part of the game.
def start_game():
        re = 1
        global servicenumber
        global exp
        if servicenumber == 1:
            while re != 0:
                notice = """
    ==============================
    Randomly generated values ​​are from 1 to 100.
    Players should enter a number between 1 and 100.
    If you win, you gain 2 exp, and if you lose, it decreases by 1.
    Please enter 0 to finish.
    ==============================\n"""
                print(notice)
                var = input('input : ')
                if var > 100:
                    print 'Please enter a value between 1 and 100.'
                    continue
                elif var < 0:
                    print 'Please enter a value between 1 and 100.'
                    continue
                elif var == 0:
                    re = 0
                else:
                    print ''

                randvalue = random.randrange(1,101)
                if var > randvalue:
                    print 'Up'
                    exp = exp + 2
                    print "exp+2"
                    print "Your experience ",exp
                    print "Randomly generated values ",randvalue
                    continue
                elif var < randvalue:
                    print 'Down'
                    exp = exp-1
                    print 'Decreasing story ~~'
                    continue
                elif var == randvalue:
                    print 'The story of being tapped ~~'
                    continue
                else:
                    print "Randomly generated values ",randvalue
                    continue
        start_screen()


def check_exp():
    global servicenumber
    if servicenumber == 2:
        print "Experience: ",exp
        start_screen()


## (exit)
def game_exit():
    global servicenumber
    if servicenumber == 3:
        print 'Exit'
        exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_screen()
else:
    print "Imported. Start unit testing.\n"
```

And the code I tried to practice
I think it is pointless.

```
import unittest
import UpDownGame

class testing(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_start(self):
        self.assertTrue(UpDownGame.start_screen)

    def test_game(self):
        self.assertTrue(UpDownGame.start_game)

    def test_chkexp(self):
        self.assertTrue(UpDownGame.check_exp)

    def test_exit(self):
        self.assertTrue(UpDownGame.game_exit)


def initialize():
    return testing


if __name__ == "__main__":
    testsuite = (unittest.makeSuite(testing))
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(testsuite)
```

So I want advice on unit testing.
I would really appreciate it if you let me know how to apply unit tests to this code.
Also, let me know if you think I have the basic knowledge I need.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to write the tests when you've already written the code, and you've started with inherently hard to test code. If you wrote the tests before each part of code they are intended to test then you would write the code quite differently.

So, ignoring your code entirely, you want a 'start_screen' function that will print a prompt, read some input, and call a function based on that input. You don't want to hard-wire the functions that get called (because that makes it harder to test), so you might change the function so it takes a dictionary of actions and then you can pass in test actions in place of the ones the real code will run. You also don't want it reading from `input()` so again you might make that customisable. Writing output with `print` is also a bad idea for testing, as you'll want to catch the output if you need to make any assertions about it but we'll ignore that for now.

So, change `def start_screen()` to:

```
DEFAULT_ACTIONS = { 1: start_game, 2: check_exp, 3: game_exit }
def start_screen(actions=DEFAULT_ACTIONS, input=input):
    pass
```

and write a test:

```
def test_start_input_1_calls_action_1(self):
    calls = []
    dummy_actions = { 1: lambda: calls.append('action1') }
    def dummy_input():
        calls.append('input')
        return 1
    start_screen(actions=dummy_actions, input=dummy_input)
    assert calls == ['input', 'action1']
```

next you verify that the test compiles and runs and fails with an assertion error. If it fails for any other reason you fix the test.

Only then, you change `start_screen` so that the test now passes.

Then you can add other tests. A good next test would be one where the 'input' function returns 4 the first time it is called and then a 1:

```
def test_start_input_4_prompts_again(self):
    calls = []
    inputs = [1, 4]
    dummy_actions = { 1: lambda: calls.append('action1') }
    def dummy_input():
        calls.append('input')
        return inputs.pop(0)
    start_screen(actions=dummy_actions, input=dummy_input)
    assert calls == ['input', 'input', 'action1']
```

Now you verify that you get an assertion error, then you modify the code so that the test passes. Now the most important step: you look at the two tests and see that they are almost identical so you remove the duplication to another function and modify the tests so they look something like this:

```
def test_start_input_1_calls_action_1(self):
   self.start_helper([1], ['input', 'action1'])

def test_start_input_4_prompts_again(self):
   self.start_helper([4, 1], ['input', 'input', 'action1'])

def start_helper(self, inputs, expected_calls):
    ... add code here ...
```

then go on to write tests for the other functions. You will want to lose the global variable: tested functions need to be clean and not depend on variables set outside. Also that recursive call it probably the wrong thing to do, you might want to consider making `start_screen` have a loop and in that case the tests we just wrote will have to be updated for that.

At every step the fact that you have already written the test is going to influence how you think about the code.